# How to download lots of files concurrently in android?

Tags: android, file

I want to download a number of files concurrently in android, for instance, there are 10000 files to be downloaded, each file have small size about 20kb, and I want 3 threads concurrently download the files.

Maybe Asynctask is suitable? And may be a queue is needed to manage the 10000 urls?

There are some comments mentioned DownloadManager.class, does it support concurrent download? Because there are too many files and file size is small, I think concurrently doing it will be faster.

Comment: Maybe DownloadManager is suitable for you: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: Use _DownloadManager_

Answer (score 0):

I think AsyncTask will be suitable for this.
You can create two Queues say, runningTasks and pendingTasks.

When ever you try to download a task put it in the runningTasks list and other tasks in the pendingTasks list. Execute the tasks added in the running tasks List using AsyncTask handler .
Add a listener for whenever a task gets completed. remove a task from pendingTasks and add it in the pendingTasks list.
See the Logic Implmented Below:-

```
public class Downloader
{
    AsyncTaskScheduler scheduler;

    public Downloader()
    {
        scheduler  = new AsyncTaskScheduler();
    }

    public void startDownload()
    {
        long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        YourAsyncTask handler = new YourAsyncTask();
        scheduler.schedule(handler, ts);

    }

}
          public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
{          
    AsyncTaskScheduler listener;
    String Uri;              
    public YourAsyncTask(AsyncTaskScheduler listener, uri)     
    {     
        this.Uri = uri;     
        this.listener = listener;     
    }            
    @Override       protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params)
    {     
        try {     
            //Do Http Download here from The URI
            // return the Bitmap downloaded ;

        return bitmap;     
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();     
        }                
        return null;     
    }            
    @Override     
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)     
    {        
        this.listener.DownloadCompleted(this);     
    }
     }     



public class TaskInfo
{          
    AsyncTask< Void , Void, Bitmap> async;     
    long timeStamp;                  
    public TaskInfo(){}              
    public TaskInfo(AsyncTask< Void , Void, Bitmap> async, long timeStamp)     
    {     
        this.async = async;     
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;          
    }          
    public AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> getHandler()     
    {     
        return this.async;     
    }            
    public long getTimeStamp()     
    {     
        return this.timeStamp;     
    }     
     }     

public interface DownloaderCompleted
{          
    void DownloadCompleted(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> task);
         }

                       public class AsyncTaskScheduler implements DownloaderCompleted
    {                    
        private static final int RUNNING_TASK_LIST_SIZE = 3;                  
        public ArrayList<TaskInfo> runningTasks;          
        public LinkedList<TaskInfo> pendingTasks;                    
        public AsyncTaskScheduler()         
        {         
            runningTasks = new ArrayList<TaskInfo>();          
            pendingTasks = new LinkedList<TaskInfo>();         
        }                    
        public void schedule(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> handler, long timeStamp)         
        {         
            //Running Task list is not Full add some task to it         
            TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo(handler,timeStamp);         
            if (!isRunningtaskListFull())         
            {         
                runningTasks.add(taskInfo);                              
                //Check if the task added to the running list , is there in the pending list also , then remove it.         
                for(int i = 0; i< pendingTasks.size();i++)         
                {                                
                    if (pendingTasks.get(i).getVideoId().equals(videoId))         
                    {         
                        pendingTasks.remove(i);         
                        break;         
                    }         
                }                            
                taskInfo.getHandler().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);                             
            } else         
            {         
                //Check if the task is in the pending list , if Yes then No Need to Add it.         
                 boolean found = false;         
                for(int i = 0; i< pendingTasks.size();i++)         
                {         
                    if (pendingTasks.get(i).getVideoId().equals(videoId))         
                    {         
                        found = true;         
                        break;         
                    }         
                }         
                if (found == false)         
                {         
                    pendingTasks.addFirst(taskInfo);         
                }         
            }         
        }                    
        public boolean isRunningtaskListFull()         
        {         
            if (runningTasks.size() == RUNNING_TASK_LIST_SIZE)         
            return true;         
            else                    return false;         
        }                  
        @Override           public void DownloadCompleted(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> handler)
        {         
            //check the task in the running list and remove .         
            boolean found = false;                  
            for (int i = 0; i < runningTasks.size(); i++)         
            {         
                if (runningTasks.get(i).getHandler().equals(handler))         
                {         
                    runningTasks.remove(i);         
                    found = true;         
                    break;         
                }         
            }                                            
            if (found == true )         
            {            
                if (pendingTasks.size() > 0)
                {         
                    TaskInfo taskInfo = pendingTasks.removeFirst();         
                    schedule(taskInfo.getHandler(), taskInfo.getTimeStamp());         
                } else
                {
                    //All Tasks Downloaded         
                    }         
                }         
        }         
    }
```